# Transfer Zip file from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone app that creates a zip file.

I need to provide an easy way to allow the user to transfer that zip file to their PC (not via any network connectivity, as this file could be rather large).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to accomplish this. You cannot hook into the synchronization until the next release of iPhone OS.

However, it works fine in Android.

Answer (score 0):

For development builds you can access the file through Xcode's Organizer, and save locally to the Mac.  I am not sure what is required to permit the access, perhaps the signing certificate?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone Explorer ([now iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)) works to grab files stored in an app bundle. I use it all the time.